# Pentaho connection fails with "The connection string contains a badly formed name or value"

Tags: sql-server, pentaho, pdi

Pentaho connection to MSSQL 2012 fails with:
Error occured while trying to connect to the database
The connection string contains a badly formed name or value

Answer (score 0):

Changing the connection type from "MS SQL Server (Native)" to "MS SQL Server" has resolved the issue.